# Kernel panic after running a Windows 10 virtualbox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I ran a Windows 10 on virtualbox for an hour allowing half my ram and my cores. After closing it my host remained laggy, even when moving the mouse.
I tried rebooting and I got the famous `kernel panic - attempted to kill init` message.
Since, my computer is still laggy even if I don't started the VM again, when I shutdown the computer it closes normally, when I try to reboot I get the same kernel panic.
I wanted to run a memtest86+ but I didn't managed to get it installed on a key.

I have Linux 5.3.0-45 with ubuntu mint 18.04.1
**EDIT**
After more time experimenting with an the previous kernel version, I have the lag on the system starting a few minutes after booting and the kernel panic occurs randomly on reboot or shutdown.

Comment: Can you help me with a picture and boot from the LiveUSB and grab a copy of `kern.log` in `/var/log` ?

Comment: While waiting for answers I tried with the kernel 5.3.0-42 and it seems to have resolved the problem even after rebooting to 5.3.0-45. If think kern.log only stores the last boot session so I won't be able to provide you details on the problem. I'm still worried on how this could happend but I think I'm safe as long as I don't start the VM.

Comment: I'll just wait some hours to be sure it is really solved before closing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by **Timeshift** he was trying to copy the 50Go virtualDisk file in a location with not enough space. I had to [kill it to access its gui](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/400) and disable daily saves.